# Problemas de concordancia

Tags: género, concordancia-gramatical

Entiendo esto más como una gracia, pero en serio me gustaría saber cómo se puede resolver [este dilema de concordancia](https://www.lacapital.com.ar/informacion-general/una-joven-promesa-del-futbol-fue-devorado-parcialmente-tiburones-n2556131.html) que se produce, esencialmente, porque la morfología colisiona contra la semántica, porque de verdad no creo que pueda ser correcto escribir así. ¿Lo es? ¿Hay precedentes o ejemplos ilustres reconocidos de esta discordancia?

[image: joven promesa devorado]

Por si no se ve el recorte, el mismo dice:

> ### Una joven promesa del fútbol fue devorado parcialmente por tiburones
>
> Eric Birighitti, un joven australiano de 21 años, murió tras
>   caer por un barranco en una playa al oeste de su país y ser arrastrado
>   por la marea

Comment: El periodista confunde el género gramatical con el sexo (o con el "género social").

Comment: Para mí es evidente que no es correcto. Si lo fuera, también deberíamos decir "la tortuga fue devorado" o "la jirafa fue devorado" para referirnos a un animal macho.

Answer (score 5):

Sugiero la opción "gramaticalmente correcta":

- Una joven promesa del fútbol fue devorada parcialmente por los tiburones.

No veo ningún problema con esta frase. Si en lugar de "una joven promesa" fuera

- Una persona fue devorada parcialmente por los tiburones

nadie se sorprendería de que "devorada" esté en femenino aunque la persona sea un hombre. No veo la diferencia entre este caso y el de "una joven promesa".

Esta sugerencia tiene la ventaja añadida de que se puede interpretar en sentido figurado como que "la promesa fue devorada". Tiene un tono casi literario que no tiene por qué venir mal en un titular.

Comment: Un titular periodístico intencionalmente poético (y ni cursi ni cliché) sería una noticia sorprendente en sí misma. :)

Answer (score 4):

Además del problema de concordancia, observo un problema con "devorado parcialmente". Si murió, claramente fue más que una mordida, pero me causa cierta extrañeza la combinación de "devorar" (bastante totalizador) con "parcialmente".

En cuanto al sujeto, ocurre que "promesa" es, como sabemos, un sustantivo abstracto que se utiliza en este caso para describir a un sustantivo concreto ("joven"). El problema es que se usó "promesa" como núcleo del sujeto y "joven" (adjetivo) como modificador.

Este titular no hubiera estado tan mal:

> Joven promesa del fútbol fue devorado parcialmente por tiburones.

(Joven (que era una) promesa del fútbol fue devorado parcialmente por tiburones.)

Otra opción sería usar la forma expandida del titular anterior, pero las cláusulas relativas son bastante incompatibles con los titulares:

- Joven que era promesa del fútbol fue devorado parcialmente por tiburones.

El uso del artículo, aunque correcto, hubiera parecido a primera vista completamente no gramatical:

- Un joven promesa del fútbol fue devorado parcialmente por tiburones.

(Un joven (que era (una) promesa del fútbol) fue devorado parcialmente por tiburones.)